# TCP/IP server in C++ is not waiting for client

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, qt-creator

I found some code in the internet with some basics about creating an TCP/IP server in C++.
I took this code, added some libraries and some lines of code. The result is, that I am able to compile and run the code/server in Qt Creator on Windows as a console program. Nevertheless I am not able to connect to the server because it just runs through the code without waiting and accepting a connection from an TCP client.

This is the code:
EDIT: Code is updated and it's now working. Test against == -1 is the solution.

```
#define PORT 2000
#define MAX_QUEUE 5
#define BUF_SIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char* const argv[])
{
cout << "Hello World!" << endl;    
        WSADATA wsaData;
int wsaret = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD( 4, 4 ), &wsaData);
cout << "wsaret: " << wsaret << endl;

cout << "Start TCP/IP Server" << endl;

/* file descriptors for sockets */
SOCKET sock_1, sock_2;  //switched from in to SOCKET //unsigned int sock_1, sock_2;
int rec_value, length;
char buf[BUF_SIZE];

//struct sockaddr_in server;
struct sockaddr_in server;

/* create stream socket in internet domain*/
sock_1 = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
//if(sock_1 < 0)
if(sock_1 == -1)
{
    cout << "socket: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl; //instead of //cout << "socket: " << strerror(errno) << endl; //cout << "socket wsaret: " << wsaret << endl;
    exit(1);
}

/* build address in internet domain */
server.sin_family = AF_INET;

/* everyone is allowed to connet to server */
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; //inet_addr("192.168.145.129");
server.sin_port = htons(2000);  //server.sin_port = PORT; //Port: 2000

/* bind socket */
//if(bind(sock_1, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)));
int bindreturn = (bind(sock_1, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)));
if(bindreturn == -1)
{
    cout << "bind: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl; //instead of //cout << "bind: " << strerror(errno) << endl; //cout << "bind wsaret: " << wsaret << endl;
    exit(1);
}

listen(sock_1,MAX_QUEUE);
    /* start accepting connection */
    sock_2 = accept(sock_1,0,0);
    if(sock_2 < 0)
    {
        cout << "accept: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    /* read from sock_2 */
    while(rec_value=recv(sock_2,buf,BUF_SIZE,0))
    {
        if(rec_value < 0)

        {
         cout << "recv: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
         exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "else" << endl;
            send(sock_2,"1,2,3",strlen("1,2,3"),0);
        }
    }

    cout << "Ending connection" << endl;
    closesocket(sock_1);
    closesocket(sock_2);
    cout << "End TCP/IP Server" << endl;

    WSACleanup();
return 0;
}
```

The console shows the following after/during running the program in one or less seconds:

```
Hello World!
wsaret: 0
Start TCP/IP Server
bind: 0
```

What can I do, that the server waits for an connection partner?

Thanks in advance.

Regards
matl

Edit: Added a few lines of code at the beginning, which I forgot before.
Edit: Code update
Edit: Code update

Comment: Doesnt' seem like you've included all the code? For a start, the part where the "Hello World!" line is printed isn't included in the code. Maybe if you included the full code, it'll be easier to see what went wrong?

Also, if I were to hazard a guess, I'd say that you'd need to include command line arguments with bind port etc when running the actual executable.

Comment: Since the `bind` fails, any subsequent operation is also bound to fail. Most likely is probably that some other process is already listening to the port. Check `errno` to determine what went wrong.

Comment: You're reporting errors and then ignoring them completely and proceeding as though they hadn't happened. A listen or bind error is*fatal.* Nothing can work after than. And just printing the -1 isn't acceptable either. You must print the *error,* via `perror()` or `strerror()`. Don't write code like this.

Comment: Hey thanks for your hints. I added strerror() to the code. So in general the program fails within the socket() call, but I don't know why. strerror() says "No error" but nevertheless sock_1 is "-1" which means that there is an error.   
I updated the code above.

Comment: Sigh. What did `WSAGetLastError()` return?

Comment: 1. Your error tests are invalid. It isn't correct to test for < -1. A socket FD for example can have any value *except* -1. You should test the result of every system call for `== -1`.

2. As you're using Winsock, `errno` and friends don't work. Use `WSAGetLastError()`.

3. Note also that it isn't valid to test `errno` or call `perror()` or `strerror()` unless you do so *immediately* after a system call which has failed. Your code outputs the result of `WSAGetLastError()` first, which calls other syserm calls in the process, which disturbs the value of `errno`.

Comment: I updated the code again. So you can see the newest one. I general I am not testing agains "-1". I am testing again "<0". I also commented the strerror stuff, so I just using WSAGetLastError instead.

Comment: Then you are just wasting time. It is pointless to post here unless you take some notice of what you're told. **FIX** your code according to what you're told here, retest, and tell us the result. Specifically, test every system call for a return value of exactly -1. And get rid of that extra `;` in the line that calls `bind()`.

Comment: Ah sorry, I missunderstood the part, that I should just test against == -1.

Comment: Testing against == -1 let bind() run successfully and I can then connect to the server. While sending any messages to the server, it will answer with "1,2,3" so it is now working for me. Thank you all for your patience!

Comment: @EJP - _"And get rid of that extra ; in the line that calls bind()"_ - Ah yes, I forgot to mention that one (I needed to remove it to be able to compile..).

Comment: You misunderstood 'you should test the result of every system call for `== -1`'? How?

Comment: Language problem. Just read about your lines without thinking about it. Sorry EJP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to comment in detail on the original code you posted.

```
cout << "Start TCP/IP Server" << endl;

//int sock_1,sock_2;     /* file descriptors for sockets */
int sock_1, sock_2;
int rec_value, length;
char buf[BUF_SIZE];

//struct sockaddr_in server;
sockaddr_in server;

/* create stream socket in internet domain*/
sock_1 = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);//0);
```

Missing test here. You must test the result for -1 along these lines:

```
if (sock_1 == -1)
{
    cout << "socket creation error: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    exit(1); // or some other measure to prevent continuation
}
```

Back to your code:

```
/* build address in internet domain */
server.sin_family = AF_INET;

/* everyone is allowed to connet to server */
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; //inet_addr("192.168.145.129");
server.sin_port = PORT; //Port: 2000
```

That should be

```
server.sin_port = htons(PORT);
```

Back to your code:

```
/* bind socket */
int bindreturn = bind(sock_1, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));
cout << "bindreturn: " << bindreturn << endl;
```

Inadequate. Here again you need to test for -1, and print `WSAGetLastError()` and exit if you got it.

```
listen(sock_1,MAX_QUEUE);
```

Untested. Here again you need to test for -1 etc.

```
    /* start accepting connection */
    //system("pause");
    sock_2 =accept(sock_1,0,0);
    //system("pause");
    cout << "acceptreturn: " << sock_2 << endl;
```

Inadequate again, see above.

```
    /* read from sock_2 */
    while(rec_value=recv(sock_2,buf,BUF_SIZE,0))
    {
        if(rec_value<0)
        {
         cout << "error: " << rec_value << endl;
         exit(1);
        }
```

Test is incorrect. A system call indicates error by returning exactly -1, not just any value < 0. A socket FD for example returned by `socket()` or `accept()` can be negative, or any value other than -1.

```
        else
        {
            cout << "else" << endl;
            send(sock_2,"1,2,3",strlen("1,2,3"),0);
        }
    }
closesocket(sock_1);
closesocket(sock_2);

cout << "End TCP/IP Server" << endl;

return 0;
```

It is apparent from the `closesocket()` calls that you're using Winsock, in which case both `WSAStart()` and `WSACleanup()` are missing.

Answer (score 2):

How is `PORT` defined?

You should use:

```
server.sin_port = htons(PORT); //Port: 2000
```

Is your IP-address correct?

All your calls are receiving `SOCKET_ERROR` (-1), so you should check lasterror to get more information.

Not sure (on Windows here), but shouldn't those be `unsigned int`'s?

```
int sock_1, sock_2;
```

**Update**:

Ok, you seem to be using Qt on Windows.

For Qt, you might as well use the [Qt libraries](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtnetwork-module.html).

On Windows in general, you could use the free MS Visual Studio.

You also need to call `WSAStartup()` like this:

```
WSADATA wsaData;
int wsaret = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD( 4, 4 ), &wsaData);
// check wsaret

// more code here

WSACleanup();
```

Also use `SOCKET`:

```
SOCKET sock_1, sock_2;
```

Check the errorcodes with `WSAGetLastError()`.

Comment: I'm creating a small C++ console programm with Qt Creator without Qt in it on a Windows machine.    If I'm not wrong "server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;" allwos every IP adress. I'm using "server.sin_port = htons(2000);" now, but bind() is still failing.

Comment: @matl - how far do you get with the new code? Also, don't forget `htons(PORT)`. Also check returncode from listen(). And your ´accept()´ needs better parameters.

Comment: Are you using winsock2 then? (you might need SOCKET instead of int). Or any Qt libraries? Because the code you found was almost certainly written for linux. What headers are you including?

Comment: On Windows you also need: ` WSAStartup(). That's probably your first problem. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @matl - INADDR_ANY -> indeed, but there was an IP address too, so you might have been switching between the two for testing.

Comment: Hey, SOCKET instead of in solved the first problem. Now socket_1 is not -1. But the bind function still offers me -1.

strerror(errno) and WSAGetLastError() tell me, "Result too large" and "0".

Comment: I'm including stdio.h, ctype.h, iostream, string, cmath, ctime, conio.h, errno.h, stdlib.h and windows.h. I have no changes if I include winsock2.h or winsock.h or if I just leave it.

Comment: Did you call `WSAStartup()`? It won't work without it :)

Comment: Yes, I think I called the function. I also updated the code on the top. :)

Comment: Oh, and what was the value of `wsaret `? :) You need to check that too.

Comment: @matl - Ok, I did a test here, corrected `server.sin_port = ntohs(PORT); //Port: 2000` - compiled your code (from within Visual Studio), and is seems to work (browser to server and back to browser). I didn't do full testing! - And you should definitely check all your return codes + check your `accept()` parameters. Just in case: try another portnr maybe. Also try to step through it with your debugger.

Comment: During the failure of bind() wsaret is 0 similar to WSAGetLastError(). Strerror(errno) tells me again "Result too large".

Comment: @matl - you don't need `errno` if you use `WSAGetLastError()`.

Comment: Ok, thought using both gives me more details about the error. If I am just using "cout << "bind: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;" then the result is 0 which is nevertheless an error.

Comment: He is passing correct parameters to `accept()`. The second parameter can be null, in which case the third parameter is ignored.

Comment: @matl - link to the error codes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668.aspx

Comment: @EJP - Indeed, I overlooked that - thx (did compile and run here with the 0's).